# Why do some Microsoft Office drawing objects in PowerPoint print in different grayscale modes?

Tags: microsoft-office, printing, microsoft-powerpoint, drawing, grayscale

In PowerPoint 2016*, you can copy groups of Visio objects directly into a presentation, then edit them by right-clicking them and selecting "Edit Picture". A dialog will appear warning that the object is an imported picture, not a group, and that it will need to be converted to a Microsoft Office drawing object.

[image: Screenshot of dialog produced when editing a pasted picture from Visio in PowerPoint.]

After the conversion, you can edit the individual elements of the drawing object to your heart's content.

However, later on, if you go to make sure that the presentation looks good when printed out in grayscale, you may find something strange; some objects use different grayscale modes from other objects. For instance, you may have one imported group with colored text appear in the "Black with Grayscale fill" and another in the "Grayscale" mode. When you go to print, the first group will print the colored text in black, while the other will print it in a shade of gray.

It's possible to fix this problem by selecting all troublesome objects in the slide, going to grayscale Auto mode with View->Grayscale, clicking the Grayscale button that appears in the ribbon to force all the objects into Grayscale mode, then returning to Color View.

Why is this? Is there a way to prevent it?

*Exact PowerPoint string from About dialog: `Microsoft® PowerPoint® 2016 MSO (16.0.4849.1000) 64-bit`

Comment: Please refer to [Print a presentation in black and white or grayscale](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/print-a-presentation-in-black-and-white-or-grayscale-2e5cc436-3181-49e3-92ed-84c15eb829ee) . Is there any text shadow in drawing objects?

Comment: Thanks for the link - it confirms that the grayscale mode can be set on a per object basis. To answer your question, in the file where I first encountered this, there are no shadows in the objects. The objects consist of a collection of squares with borders. Some of the squares have fill, some of the squares have text, some have both. Both are fixed by changing the grayscale type. Unfortunately, I can't post it here.